# Finding the first decimal in a string

Tags: ruby

I have strings that consist of two lots of numbers. I am trying to split them into two substrings so that there are two decimal places after each decimal.

I have this code:

```
if homeodds.length == 10 then
   homeoddsp = homeodds[0,5].to_f
   bookieh = homeodds[5,5].to_f
else
   homeoddsp = homeodds[0,4].to_f
   bookieh = homeodds[4,4].to_f
end
```

It handles an eight figure string fine:
`"1.211.90"` translates to `"1.21"` and `"1.90"`.

and a ten figure string also works:
`"12.2113.00"` translates to `"12.21"` and `"13.00"`.

When I have a nine figure string like `"9.1110.00"` or `"10.119.55"`, I need to find out where the first decimal is, and take two digits after that so that the remainder becomes the second substring. These cases, I can't consistently do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `String#scan` for this particular problem

```
def decimal_splits(string)
  string.scan(/\d+\.\d{2}/)
end
```

To break down the regular expression:

- `\d+` 1 or more number of digits
- `\.` the decimal point
- `\d{2}` two digits

The result will be an array of matches for the expression.

```
decimal_splits("9.1110.00")
#=> ["9.11", "10.00"]
decimal_splits("12.2113.00")
#=> ["12.21", "13.00"]
decimal_splits("1.211.90")
#=> ["1.21", "1.90"]
decimal_splits("10.119.55")
#=> ["10.11", "9.55"]
```